# Array format showing as object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

hope you are doing well. I have faced an issue. I'm creating a dynamic array but when I console that variable and check typeOf of this variable it showing an object instead of an array. Also when I access a specific element of that variable it's showing undefined. Let me know how can I resolve this issue. you can check I have declared a global variable name of test and push data in it. it should return an array because I'm pushing it in the array. But showing object.

```
$(document).ready(async function(){
           await load_pre_data(true);
       });

       let pre_data= [];
       let count = 1;
       var test = [];
       let  ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089');
      async function load_pre_data() {
           ws.onopen = function (evt) {
               ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                   ticks_history: 'frxAUDJPY',
                   adjust_start_time: 1,
                   count: 5,
                   end: "latest",
                   start: 1,
                   style: "ticks"
               }));
           };
           ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
               let response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
               let loop;
               for (loop = 0; loop <= response.history.prices.length; loop++) {
                    test.push(1);
               }
           }
          console.log(test);
          console.log(typeof (test));
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript every array is the type of an object and for your typechecking you can use "Array.isArray(test)".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

You can read about isArray() method here

Comment: but if it's an array why I can not able to access a single value. like this test[0]..??

Comment: Because there is no element has added to the array when you call the console. The console logs the data as soon as it gets called. I think you u should use console in the on message event after for loop

Comment: And you haven't called the onmessage event before the console log so there is literally no value in the test at 0 index

Comment: Can I not access the specific value anywhere on the page because I have declared the variable globally...??

Comment: By the way onmessage is socket function it's automatically called. I'm facing that issue i am not able to access the specific value of test in the page.